Is the real number line $\mathbb{R}$ with the compact complement topology simply connected?
Let $\mathbb{E}^1$ denote $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard Euclidean topology. Let $X$ denote $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology for which a nonempty subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if its complement $\mathbb{R} \backslash U$ is compact as a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^1$. This is called the compact complement topology in [SS].
Question: Is $X$ simply connected?
To paint a bit of a picture, note that the topology on $X$ is coarser than the Euclidean topology. This means that the identity function $\mathbb{E}^1 \to X$ is continuous, so it clearly follows that $X$ is arc-connected (each pair of distinct points is connected by an injective path $[0, 1] \to X$). The topology on $X$ is finer than the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, for which nonempty open sets are exactly the complements of finite sets; this is equivalent to $X$ being $T_1$ [SS, Item 1]. Observe also that $X$ has no disjoint nonempty open subsets, which means it is hyperconnected (= irreducible) [SS, Item 3]. It easily follows from hyperconnectedness that $X$ is not Hausdorff. Unlikely, but perhaps it's relevant to mention that $X$ is compact, since the complement of any chosen set in an open cover is compact, so finitely many of the others plus the chosen set must cover $X$ [SS, Item 4].
This answer in the thread Path-connected subsets of compact complement topology says that any subset of $X$ containing an unbounded interval is path-connected, and speculates that a set which does not contain an unbounded interval is path-connected if and only if it is path-connected as a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^1$. Taking this for granted, it seems like the idea may be that the path $[0, 1] \to X$ from $0$ to $1$ which is the restriction of the identity function shouldn't be path homotopic to a path from $0$ to $1$ with image $(-\infty, 0] \cup \{1\}$, but I don't know how to argue this.
The thread Is the compact complement topology locally arc connected? may also have potentially useful information.
It may be interesting to compare with superficially similar spaces. I.e,

The finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible. See here.
The countable complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, for which open sets are the empty set and the complements of countable sets, is connected but not even path-connected. See this answer.

[SS] Steen, L. A.; Seebach, J. A. jun., Counterexamples in topology, New York etc.: Holt, Rinehart and Winston, Inc., XIII, 210 p. (1970). ZBL0211.54401.

Consider $H:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $H(t,x)=tx$. I think it still is continuous. And thus the space is contractible.

It's a bit like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected.

@freakish This is not true. For example, consider the open set $U=(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$. $H^{-1}(U)$ is not open. Indeed, $(0,0)\in H^{-1}(U)$, so if $H^{-1}(U)$ were open, there would be some $\epsilon>0$ and $V\subset X$ nonempty open s.t. $H([0,\epsilon)\times V)\subset U$. But the complement of $V$ is bounded, so in particular there exists $x\in V$ s.t. $x>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Hence, $\frac{1}{x}\in[0,\epsilon)$, but $H(\frac{1}{x},x)=\frac{1}{x}\cdot x=1\notin U$.

@DavidGao $(0,0)$ does not belong to $H^{-1}(U)$.

@freakish What do you mean? $H(0,0)=0\in U$, no? Note that $U$ is not $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$. It is just $\mathbb{R}\setminus{1}$.

@DavidGao I see, you meant $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$, not "$-1$". Yeah, I think you're right.

After a lot of thinking about this, I'm pretty convinced that if we map $S^1$ into $X$ by mapping the north and south pole to $0$, and the two arcs connecting them to the intervals $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ (such that the south pole "directions" both go outward), we get a loop that is not nullhomotopic. I've been unable to prove it so far, however.

The answer is Yes.
Definition. Let $U(x,\epsilon)=(-\infty,x-\epsilon^{-1})\bigcup (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\bigcup (x+\epsilon^{-1},\infty)$ be some special open set in $X$.
Note that a function $f$ from an arbitrary space $Y$ to $X$ is continuous iff: when identifying $X$ as $\mathbb{R}$, for any point $p\in Y$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a neighborhood of $p$ which for every point $q$, $f(q)\in U(f(p),\epsilon)$.
Definition. For $p,q\in X$, "The straight line" from $p$ to $q$ is a path: $f(t)‎ = p+t(q-p),t\in [0,1]$. We denote $f$ as $L(p,q)$.
Definition. Let $K_+ (p,q)$ be the path: $f(t)‎ = \frac{t}{1-t}+p, t\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=q$. Let $K_- (p,q)$ be the path: $f(t)‎ = \frac{t}{t-1}+p,t\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=q$. One can verify these two paths are continuous (as map to $X$).
Claim 1. $K_+(0,0)$ is null-homotopic. As a corollary, $K_+(p,q)$ and $K_- (p,q)$ are homotopic to $L(p,q)$.
Proof. Let $f=K_+(0,0)$. We construct another loop $g:[0,1]\rightarrow X$, which is "many $f$ piled up": For $x\in [1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}) (n\in \mathbb{Z}^+)$, say $x=(1-t)(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + t(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}})$, let $g(x)=f(t)+n-1$, and let $g(1)=0$. One can use the criterion above to verify that $g$ is continuous. Let $h_1:[-1,1]\rightarrow X$, $h_1(x)=f(x+1)$ when $x<0$, $h_1(x)=g(x)+1$ when $0\le x<1$ and $h_1(1)=0$. We can view $h_1$ as the product of $f$ and $g$. Let $h_2(x)=x+1$ when $-1\le x<0$ and $h_2(x)=h_1(x)$ when $x\ge 0$. Obviously $g$ and $h_2$ are homotopic. Now we construct a homotopy $H: [-1,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $h_1$ to $h_2$:
\begin{equation}
H(s,t)=\begin{cases}
s+1, & \text{if $s<-t$}\\
h_1(\frac{s+t}{1+t})-t, &\text{if $-t\le s<1$}\\
0, &\text{$s=1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
One can verify that $H$ is continuous. So the loops $h_1$ and $h_2$ are homotopic, hence $g\simeq f*g$, hence $f\simeq 0$. The corollary is trivial.
Claim 2. Every loop $f: [0,1]\rightarrow X$, which $f(0)=f(1)=q$ and $f(x) \in U(q,1)$ for every $x$, is null-homotopic.
Proof. The proof is essentially the same as the previous one. We can assume $q=0$. For $s,t\le 1$, let
$$
\phi_{s,t}(x)=\begin{cases}
ts^{-1} x, & |x|<s\\
st^{-1} x, & |x|>s^{-1}
\end{cases}
$$
be a continuous one-to-one mapping from $U(0,s)$ to $U(0,t)$. The loop $g:[0,1]\rightarrow X$: for $x\in [1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}) (n\in \mathbb{Z}^+)$, say $x=(1-t)(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + t(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}})$, let $g(x)=\phi_{1,(n+1)^{-1}} \circ f(t)$, and $g(1)=0$. As the previous case, extend $g$ to $h_2$: $h_2(x)=0$ for $-1\le x<0$ and $h_2(x)=g(x)$ for $0\le x\le 1$. Let $h_1$ be the homotopy product: $h_1(x)=f(x+1)$ for $-1\le x<0$ and $h_1(x)=g(x)$ for $0\le x\le 1$. The homotopy is given by
\begin{equation}
H(s,t)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $s<-t$}\\
\phi_{1,(n+1-t)^{-1}}\circ f(w), &\text{if $-t\le s<1$ and $\frac{s+t}{1+t}=(1-w)(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + w(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}})$}\\
0, &\text{$s=1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Hence $f\simeq 0$.
Finally we solve the original problem. It suffices to prove that any loop $f$ which $f(0)=f(1)=0$ is null-homotopic.
By continuity, for every $e\in [0,1]$, there is a neighborhood (open interval containing $e$) where $f(x)\in U(f(e),1)$ for each $x$. By the compactness of $[0,1]$, it is covered by finite number of those intervals, so we can divide $[0,1]$ into $n$ parts: $[0(=d_0),d_1],\dots,[d_{n-1},d_n(=1)]$, such that for each interval there exists $e_i\in [d_{i-1},d_i]$ that $f(x)\in U(f(e_i),1)$ for $x$ in $[d_{i-1},d_i]$. Let $f_i$ be the path induced by this interval. We will show that $f_i$ is homotopic to $L(f(d_{i-1}),f(d_i))$, hence the whole loop is null-homotopic.
Let $a=L(f(e_i),f(d_{i-1})), b=L(f(d_i),f(e_i))$. We show that there exists a path $c$ from $f(e_i)$ to $f(d_{i-1})$ with value in $U(f(e_i),1)$ which is homotopic to $a$. Indeed, if $d_{i-1}$ lies in $(f(e_i)-1,f(e_i)+1)$, let $c=a$; if it lies in $(f(e_i)+1,\infty)$, let $c=(K_+ (f(d_{i-1}),f(e_i)))^{-1}$ be the reverse path of $K_+$. By claim 1, $c$ and $a$ are homotopic. If $d_{i-1}$ lies in $(-\infty,f(e_i)-1)$, let $c= (K_- (f(d_{i-1}),f(e_i)))^{-1}$.
In the same way, let $d$ be the path from $f(d_i)$ to $f(e_i)$ with value in $U(f(e_i),1)$ and homotopic to $b$. By our second claim, $c* f_i * d$ (as a loop valued in $U(f(e_i),1)$) is a null-homotopic loop, hence $f_i$ is homotopic to $a^{-1} * b^{-1}$, hence homotopic to the straight line $L(f(d_{i-1}),f(d_i))$ . The proof is done.

I made a couple comments based on a misreading (now deleted), but I'm still confused by your reasoning, particularly that having "straight lines" from $f(d_{i-1})$ to $f(d_i)$ should mean the whole loop is nullhomotopic. What if some of these straight lines go through $1$ or $-1$, so your second claim does not apply?

For example, suppose we simply map $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the standard way, and map $0,1 \in [0,1]$ to $0$. What homotopy would your construction generate for this loop?

@MartianInvader The first claim is used to construct a path which is homotopic to the straight line but doesn't pass $1$ or $-1$. (I'm sorry the proof is a bit unclear. I'll rewrite that later). To your second question: your map is the product of two loops of the type in the first claim, hence each is null-homotopic.

Okay, and can you explain in more detail how you can use the compactness of $[0,1]$ to generate the $d_i$ and $e_i$? I don't see how it works.

@MartianInvader I've edited the answer and you can see the detail.

Thanks, your argument is clearer now. I don't think your $g$ is continuous. For example, the inverse image of $X \setminus {1}$ contains $1$ but no neighborhood of it.

I also still don't understand how the construction of the $e_i$ and $d_i$ would work. For example, using your $f$ as an example, what would be the interval containing $1$?

When you write "$g$ and $h_2$ are homotopic", is there a minor mistake here (since they have different domains), or am I misunderstanding something?

@MartianInvader I guess you are refering to the proof of first claim. In the construction of $g$ you can see that when $x$ is close to $1$, $f(x)$ become very large, so those $x$ are in fact in the inverse image of $X\setminus {1}$. (It's better to draw a graph and see what $g$ looks like)

@MartianInvader to your second question: for example, $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. (Note that intervals like $(0.5,1]$ is also called "open" in the space $[0,1]$)

@GeoffreySangston They indeed have different domains, but you can consider them as loops. Explicitly, what I meant is: let $i(x)=h_2 (2x-1)$, so $i$ is a "standard" loop with domain $[0,1]$, and $i$ is homotopic to $g$.

I wasn't sure if @MartianInvader was talking about the first $g$ or the second $g$, so I deleted this earlier. But here's a partial graph of the first $g$; it also includes some other functions from PureRun89's post. It only includes 3 of the "piled up" f's since it renders pretty slowly already. https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/e9kr6xj6

I think, aside from minor nitpicks I found, it is correct. So I'm upvoting, but I'll wait some time before accepting to see if anybody has something to share or wants clarification.
The way you showed $f$ is null-homotopic really surprised me. I guess not, but is it possible to explicitly write down a simple null-homotopy for $f$?

I still say the first $g$ is not continuous. The inverse image of ${1}$ (or any positive singleton) contains a point in each of the tiny intervals approaching $1$, therefore contains a sequence approaching $1$. But it does not contain $1$, therefore it is not closed. Therefore its complement, the inverse image of $X \setminus {1}$ (or the complement of any positive singleton), is not open. So the inverse image of an open set under $g$ is not open, thus $g$ is not continuous.

To put it in a way that directly addresses @PureRun89's response, it doesn't matter that the inverse image contains most of the points near $1$. It excludes a set of points that get arbitrarily close to $1$, thus it does not fully contain any neighborhood of $1$

@MartianInvader please, just see what $g$ looks like (the OP drew that in geogebra in a link above) and you will find you are wrong. The inverse image of ${1}$ only contains TWO points.

@MartianInvader I suspect you missed that each additional "piled up" $f$ in $g$ is incremented upwards by 1 unit. Continuity of $g$ at each point of $[0, 1)$ follows from inductive application of the pasting lemma, since $f$ (really each $K_+(n, n+1)$ with horizontal rescaling) is continuous. Continuity at $1$ follows from the criterion PureRun89 mentioned, since the $f$'s keep incrementing upwards.

Thanks, I do see that $g$ is continuous now. I'm still working on trying to understand the rest of the argument.

@GeoffreySangston To answer your question "Is it possible to explicitly write down a simple null-homotopy for $f$", you can get a nullhomotopy from the argument. Basically you balloon out a $g\circ g^{-1}$ from $0$ to get a homotopy from $f$ to $f\circ g\circ g^{-1}$, then do the shifting in the construction to have the $g$ "absorb" the $f$ so you get a homotopy to $g\circ g^{-1}$, then perform the obvious nullhomotopy on $g\circ g^{-1}$. I'll leave you to decide if that counts as "simple" :)

@MartianInvader Good point, though I actually added 'simple' as a safeguard against exactly that being the answer. I was intending on trying to simplify the result of that some time over the break.
